# Send notification from server to desktop program

Tags: c#, php, sockets, tcp, real-time

I created a php program on server side

```php
    $host = "my server ip";
    $port = port;
    set_time_limit(0);
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
    $result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
    $result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
    $input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");
    $input = trim($input);
    echo "Client Message : ".$input;
    socket_write($spawn, $input, strlen ($input)) or die("Could not write output\n");
    socket_close($spawn);
    socket_close($socket);
```

and create a c# winform program:

```cs
    System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient clientSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
    clientSocket.Connect("185.8.175.44", 8081);
    NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
    byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("i am ready");
    serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
    serverStream.Flush();

    byte[] inStream = new byte[512 * 512 * 512];
    serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
    string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);

    richTextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(returndata) + "\n";
```

My problem is that I can not send data from the server to the desktop program.
When I start the program I receive whatever I send but after connection I am not sending data from server to desktop.

Comment: i can see youre trying to do a direct relay from a web server to your desktop app. i would suggest you use message queueing rather than using sockets, thats my opinion only. there are lots of ready to use message queueing platforms like rabbitmq. very useful at my end

Comment: tanks. rabbitmq is real time ?

Comment: yes, it is. there is an sdk that you can use to determine if a message hsa been sent frrom a server or a source. there's an event there that handles message received detection. you can deploy the rabbitmq on linux, it works well there. find it here, there's some documentation too (and its free/open source). https://www.rabbitmq.com/